# Laravel verfication.resend - The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, authentication

Odd question here. Im using the default `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` In Laravel 6. So I register ( Custom registration form ) and all works fine ( added to database etc ) then I am taken to the verification page where it has an email link to resend. When I click this I get:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

The View has this named routed in the link `route('verification.resend')`

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what's your link? where you click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/23ceaf9fa2b442362d566c94dfdc063275f0ba11/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1224). Verify resend is a POST route. So GET method is not allowed. So it should be a form Post instead.

If you are using blade something like this will get you there.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('verification.resend')) }}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in **laravel 6+** they added this route as a post so you can do it by below code

```
<a  onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('email-form').submit();">{{ __('click here to request another') }}
</a>.

<form id="email-form" action="{{ route('verification.resend') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
</form>
```